# Компилятор ругается на перегрузку оператора std::ofstream& operator<<

Tags: c++, файлы, классы, указатели, операторы

```
class day
{
    friend class product;
private:
    int number;
    double bel;
    double ygl;
    double gur;
    double kkal;
public:
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream fout, day dy)
    {
        fout<< dy.number<<std::endl;
        fout<< dy.bel <<  ' ' <<dy.gur <<  ' ' <<dy.ygl <<  ' ' <<dy.kkal<<std::endl;
    }
```

компилятор пишет:
"для 18 перегрузок есть подобные преобразования"

Comment: std::ofstream **&** fout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала - в `operator<<` передавайте поток по ссылке.

```
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& fout, day dy)
```

Во-вторых, мне кажется, лучше использовать более общий `std::ostream&`.

В-третьих, ваш оператор должен возвращать `fout`.

Comment: Сделал все как вы написали, только не обобщал до острим, все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @Макс Дайте более полный код. Желательно - [минимальный воспроизводящий проблему пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: вот то что я скинул это он и есть. 
остальные методы уже не касаются этой проблемы

Comment: @Макс Тогда не понимаю. Вот код с теми исправлениями, что я писал - http://ideone.com/MHWnXr - посмотрите, он работает.

Comment: у меня цель этой функции записать в файл.
в мейне будет запись 

day a();//сконструировал класс конструктором)
ofstream fout; //вызвал функцию для записи в файл 
fout<< a; //записал в файл созданый дей.

Comment: @Макс, `day a();` это не создание объекта, а объявление функции. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse. Уберите круглые скобки, и посмотрите что получится

Comment: в скобках у меня значение, так как конструктор принимает один аргумент